# Stopping Windows WMI Services

Tags: powershell, service, wmi

im trying to stop some Windows Services remotely on different servers but only those with a defined logon name. I already collecting the Services like this. Could you please help?
Next Step should be to stop the collected Services. Thank you!!

```
$Servers = @('server1','server2')
foreach ($i in $Servers){
Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $i | where {($_.startname -eq "Username") -or ($_.startname -eq "Username")} | select @{n='Hostname';e={$i}} ,DisplayName,Name,Startname |Out-File C:\Temp\Out.txt -Append 
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to stop services with powershell or how to implement ```Stop-Service``` in your code?

Comment: `Stop-Service -Name wuaserv`